# create table with default value that combines two columns

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to create a table with a column that combines two column values?
something like this:

create table test1
(
number1 decimal(6,2),
number2 decimal(6,2),
total decimal(6,2) DEFAULT (number1+number2)
);

Comment: do you need the possibility to assign a different value to that column as well? or is it enough to have it always computed that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a trigger:

```
create table test1
  (number1 decimal(6,2),
   number2 decimal(6,2),
   total decimal(6,2));

CREATE TRIGGER test1_bi
  BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.total is NULL THEN
    :NEW.TOTAL := :new.number1 + :new.number2;
  END IF;
END test1_bi;

INSERT INTO test1(number1, number2) VALUES(1, 2);

SELECT * FROM test1;
```

After the SELECT you'll find that TOTAL has a value of 3, as expected.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in 11G. It is called a "virtual" column.  The syntax is:

```
create table test1
 ( number1 number(6,2),
   number2 number(6,2),
   total number(6,2) generated always as (number1+number2) );
```

(There isn't a DECIMAL datatype in Oracle AFAIK, so I used NUMBER instead.)

See also: [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#BABIJABG)

NB The "generated always" keywords are optional.

The types of expression allowed after "as" are described [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions005.htm#BABIGHHI).

Comment: Just an aside - DECIMAL works fine in Oracle, but I believe it's translated to NUMBER internally.

Comment: Is it also possible to use the "generated always as" to use an inner select?

Comment: like generat always as (select sum(*) from table) or something like that?

Comment: No, you would need to calculate via a trigger in that scenario - see Bob Jarvis's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use computed columns.