# updating column value based on another column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on Library Database and it contains a table called book_transaction.
There are 2 columns called `issued_date` and `due_date`. `due_date` should be 7 days from `issued_date`. Can I specify this condition using `default` key word while creating the table?

If it is not possible  please leave an alternative for the same.

Thank you,

Comment: You can use computed column for this purpose

Comment: Thank you i got it now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the use full comment by "fabulaspb". I come up with this

```
create table book_transaction
(
  transaction_number int primary key,
  book_isbn          int REFERENCES book_master(book_isbn),
  student_code       int references student_master(student_code),
  issued_date        date default sysdate,
  due_date           date as (issued_date+7),
  submited_date      date,
  fine               int
);
```

The table is created without an error and it is working fine.
Thank you for all.

Comment: Yes, this is a smarter way of doing it.

Comment: Just a note, column due_date is a virtual column, I.e. you cannot change the value, it is ALWAYS issued_date+7

Comment: OK. Thank you for the heads-up.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle `default` constraints cannot refer to other columns.  You can get the same functionality using a trigger (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787229/50552)):

```
CREATE TRIGGER book_transaction_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON book_transaction
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.due_date IS NULL THEN
    :new.due_date := :new.issued_date + 7;
  END IF;
END book_transaction_trigger;
```

You can add days by adding a number to a `date`.

Comment: OK i know that  but can i do it without using triggers or procedures?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a trigger for the table..

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON `book_transaction` 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.issued_date = IFNULL(NEW.entryDate,NOW()),
NEW.due_date = TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,7,NEW.issued_date)
```